# Date Format On SharePoint 2013 Reports

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services, excel-services, regional-settings, date

I have Reporting Services reports and Excel Services files published in Sharepoint  2013. The date format of the regional configuration has been changed to Colombia by Date format DD / MM / YYYY.

However in reports and excel files, the date columns are shown in US format MM / DD / YYYY.

It's really important for me to solve this problem, I appreciate the collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware of the `Reporting Services` uses the locale settings based on the report server operating system.

And to can show date time format based on the `SharePoint regional settings` , you will need to set `The Language property` on a report which determines the default formats for displaying report data like date, currency, or number values.

To set the `The Language property` for a report

- In Design view, click outside the report design surface to select the report.
- In the Properties pane, for the Language property, type or select the language that you want to use for the report.

For more details check [Set the Locale for a Report (Reporting Services)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-co/library/ms159642.aspx)

**Note:** you also should make sure that

- If you are using `SQL Server 2012 SP1` and you have configured the SSRS in integrated mode and the regional setting is not reflected to your date time parameter , in this case , you will need to install `Cumulative Update 3 for SQL Server 2012 SP1`
- If you are using `SQL Server 2012`  you will need to install `Cumulative update 5 for SQL Server 2012`

**Note:**

To get the build number of your SQL version check [Get the build number of the latest Cumulative Update / Service Pack that has been installed in SQL Server](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/04/get-sql-server-build-number-latest-update-installed/)

To install suitable Cumulative update check : [FIX: The DateTime parameter is not displayed by using the regional setting format of a SharePoint website in SSRS 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2764343)

Comment: Hi, thanks you for the answer. In this case the reporting services server  is the same of sharepoint because is in integrated mode. The regional configuration of the server is spanish colombia. The data base is sql server 2014.

Comment: Yeah I've had this problem with SSRS and ended up modifying the locale on every report (I'm in AU and we use DD-MM-YYYYY) in order to get consistency.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution works for ssrs but in the case of excel services not.